# Пропал интернет на Линукс после protonvpn

Tags: linux

Установил protonvpn на Linux, сам ВПН не работал, и перестал работать интернет без впн-а. Удалил protonvpn - интернет все равно не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: VPN поменял конфигурационные файлы (default gateway и т.п.)

Comment: Вывод `ip r l` посмотрите. Скорее всего маршрут по умолчанию мимо кассы.